# Airflow - Get start time of dag run

Tags: airflow

Is it possible to get the actual start time of a dag in Airflow? By start time I mean the exact time the first task of a dag starts running.

I know I can use macros to get the execution date. If the job is ran using trigger_dag this is what I would call a start time but if the job is ran on a daily schedule then `{{ execution_date }}` returns yesterdays date.

I have also tried to place `datetime.now().isoformat()` in the body of the dag code and then pass it to a task but this seems to return the time the task is first called rather than when the dag itself started.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`{{ dag_run.start_date }}` provides the actual start time of the dag

Answer (score 14):

This is an old question, but I am answering it because the accepted answer did not work for me. `{{ dag_run.start_date }}` changes if the DAG run fails and some tasks are retried.

The solution was to use: `{{ dag_run.get_task_instance('start').start_date }}` which uses the start date of the first task (DummyOperator task with task_id: `start`).

Comment: This is very interesting.. can't try it right now but can't help to leave a comment, very useful if this is the ONLY way to get the actual start time of a DAG (regardless of retrying tasks). It does make start_time unclear if you had to retry tasks though.

Answer (score 0):

I am following the way as you stated:

> By start time I mean the exact time the first task of a dag starts running

You can still do this with macros on your first task, try this `{{ task.start_date }}`

All the variables can be found in TaskInstance class:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py#L746

Comment: This link is broken.