# set Airflow variable in UI to today.date or {{ds}}

Tags: airflow

Is there any way to set a variable in Airflow UI to get today.date() or something similar to {{ds}} in the DAG code?

I want to have flexibility to set a hard code date in variable without changing the DAG code for some use cases.

I am getting today date in DAG code right now:

```
   today = datetime.today()
```

but wanted to get it like this:

```
   today= models.Variable.get('todayVar')
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you provide more context and maybe a code snippet? In general, Airflow provides [Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#variables) that can be set in the UI and read in a DAG script.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov so how can I set variable in UI to be today date?

Comment: check airflow variables: https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#default-variables. Consider `{{ next_ds }}` and `{{ next_execution_date }}`

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of stackoverflow post:

[Airflow - Get start time of dag run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47096829/7284533)

You can achieve what you want by:

`{{ dag_run.start_date }}`

In airflow the date you are meaning is also called the 'run_date'